# Add Firebase SDK to my Swift Package Manager

Tags: swift, firebase, swift-package-manager

I want to write an internal NPM to work with Firebase Firestore, for this I need to use the Firebase SDK via SPM.
I add dependency in `Package.swift` (example below)
but I can't use it in code.

`My Package.swift` code

import PackageDescription

```
let package = Package(
    name: "FCM",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v16)],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "FCM",
            targets: ["FCM"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk", .upToNextMinor(from: "9.6.0")),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "FCM",
            dependencies: [
            ]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "FCMTest",
            dependencies: ["FCMTest"]),
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Guiseppe's answer doesn't work for me even though it goes straight from the Firebase documentation. I had to change package's name from `Firebase` to `firebase-ios-sdk`:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackage",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "MyPackage",
            targets: ["MyPackage"])
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git", from: "8.0.0")

    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "Configuration",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "FirebaseAuth", package: "firebase-ios-sdk")

            ]
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "MyPackageTests",
            dependencies: ["MyPackage"])
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `dependencies: [.package(url: ...)]` you are just saying that your `Package` will depend on the `Firebase` package.

To use a dependency package in one of your targets, you need to specify what product your target will need to depend on.

In your target add the `dependencies: []` attribute and define the firebase framework that you need by using `.product(name: , package: )`:

```swift
let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackage",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "SomeLibrary",
            targets: ["SomeTarget"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk", branch: "master")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "SomeTarget",
            dependencies: [
                // THIS WHAT MISSING
                .product(name: "FirebaseFirestore", package: "firebase-ios-sdk"),
            ]
        )
    ]
)
```

Useful links:

- [SPM documentation](https://docs.swift.org/package-manager/PackageDescription/PackageDescription.html#target)
- [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/installation-methods#via-package-dot-swift)